# Script to find any duplicates then paste over them with new data, OR if there are no duplicates - paste the new data in the next empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to compile a Database with financial information. To do this I need to import new data for each stock 'ticker' from an External API using JSON. I have been using a really good script to do this so far, which has worked in copying, transposing, and pasting the new data in the next available rows.

*However*, I am now facing problems with multiples. If new data is available for a stock, I would like to paste it over the old in the Database, and if there is no duplicates to continue with the original script to paste it at the next available row.

I think I would need an advanced **Find and Replace** function and maybe an **IF** function. I am not the best at scripting so I thought I would ask the community.

Here is the script I have been working with so far:
*(No code has been added to attempt any find and replace functions)*

```
//set spreadsheet and sheets
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const importerSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('API ImporterTest');
  const databaseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DatabaseTest');

//cash flow
  const lastRowColumnValuesCash = databaseSheet.getRange("G:G").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexCash = lastRowColumnValuesCash.length - lastRowColumnValuesCash.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//income statement
  const lastRowColumnValuesIncome = databaseSheet.getRange("AT:AT").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexIncome = lastRowColumnValuesIncome.length - lastRowColumnValuesIncome.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//balance sheet
  const lastRowColumnValuesBalance = databaseSheet.getRange("CC:CC").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexBalance = lastRowColumnValuesBalance.length - lastRowColumnValuesBalance.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//fundamentals
  const lastRowColumnValuesFund = databaseSheet.getRange("DY:DY").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexFund = lastRowColumnValuesFund.length - lastRowColumnValuesFund.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//keymetrics
  const lastRowColumnValuesMet = databaseSheet.getRange("GE:GE").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexMet = lastRowColumnValuesMet.length - lastRowColumnValuesMet.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');
//profile
  const lastRowColumnValuesProf = databaseSheet.getRange("IN:IN").getValues()
  const lastRowIndexProf = lastRowColumnValuesProf.length - lastRowColumnValuesProf.reverse()
    .findIndex(row => row[0] !== '');

//run
  if (databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 > databaseSheet.getMaxRows())
    databaseSheet.insertRowsAfter(databaseSheet.getMaxRows(),
      databaseSheet.getLastRow() + 15 - databaseSheet.getMaxRows()
    )
    importerSheet
    .getRange('F3:J40')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`G${lastRowIndexCash + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
  importerSheet
    .getRange('S3:W36')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`AT${lastRowIndexIncome + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
  importerSheet
    .getRange('AF3:AJ49')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`CC${lastRowIndexBalance + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true 
      );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('AS3:AW59')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`DY${lastRowIndexFund + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('BF3:BJ62')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`GE${lastRowIndexMet + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
    importerSheet
    .getRange('BS3:BW36')
    .copyTo(
      databaseSheet.getRange(`IN${lastRowIndexProf + 1}`),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      true
    );
};
```

**Here is the sheet which is open to editing, with hand done examples**
*https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aH-Wz8cdpaakLFNY2NlT1pSSbLH_quMdhTQIHOL1fE8/edit?usp=sharing*

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question and your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I have updated the sheet with a solution example tab. If you could check it out. It shows what I want the script to achieve. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw your sample Spreadsheet. When I saw "Solution Example" and "DatabaseTest", at "Solution Example", it seems that the background colors are changed and several cells are merged. But I cannot see about this in your script and your question. So I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail logic for achieving your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: Hello, the colors and merged cells are just so I could visually help you with understanding the solution. I need a script to search the H column in 'DatabseTest' for matches with F4 in 'API ImporterTest', then to paste everything in API ImporterTest (F3:J40, S3:W36, AF3:AJ49, AS3:AW59) transposed over that match in Column H.
BUT If there is no match, to continue with the original script which pastes the data from 'API ImporterTest' into the last empty row in 'DatabaseTest'.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. I apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue, soon.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike I have created a new sheet with examples of the two possible outcomes of my desired script. Please let me know if this is more helpful. The link is below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aH-Wz8cdpaakLFNY2NlT1pSSbLH_quMdhTQIHOL1fE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. In the case of "Example 1 (IF DUPLICATE)", you want to copy the cells "F3:N7" to "Q8:Y12". In the case of "Example 2 (IF NEW ENTRY)", you want to copy the cells "F3:N7" to "Q23:Y27". And, at the cells "P23:P27", you want to merge the cells and copy the cell "E3:E7" to "P23:P27". And, you want to execute the script by clicking the button. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes thank you that is almost correct. Example 1 destination is P8:Y12* not Q8:Y12. Apologies. Also, Example 1 is the solution for IF there is a duplicate 'Name' (a match of Column E and Column P), and Example 2 is if there is no match.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have 3 more questions for understanding your situation. I apologize for the additional questions. 1. In your situation, the search cells are always "E3:N7" on one sheet in Google Spreadsheet? 2. The updated or append cells are always "P3:Y" of the same sheet? 3. You want to copy only the cell values without including the cell format?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! 1 - It is only a duplicate in Column E and Column P that I need searched for, so E3:E is the search cells. But E3:N7 are the cells that need to be moved. 
2 - Yes in this situation it is P3:Y, but I would like it to have the possibility to call another range if possible?
3 - Please just values yes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood about the answer 3. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your answer 1 and 2. By this, I cannot still understand about your actual situation. I apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: With your first question, I am trying to say that the only match I need is between Column E and P. But you are correct that E3:N7 is the search cells.
With question 2, ignore what I said, and please try with P3:Y on the same sheet. I can change it later myself. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you use only one sheet and the destination cells are "P3:Y" for your question. About the search cells, are the search cells always only "E3:N7" on one sheet in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: About the merge cells, I think that in this case, when the cell format is also copied from the search cells to the destination cells, the script will be a simple. How about this?

Comment: I can unmerge the cells if it helps? but values only really is better.

Comment: About `I can unmerge the cells if it helps?`, copying only values can be achieved. But in your sample Spreadsheet, the column "P" is merged and also, the font size are not the default size. And, when the date is copied as only the values, the date might be changed to the serial number. How do you want to do about them?

Comment: I dont mind if the Column P needs to be unmerged, if that helps. The serial number is fine like that also.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As the result, I couldn't understand how you want to do the merged cells from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. So I proposed 2 patterns in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. **By the way, I have only your sample Spreadsheet. By this, I tested this sample script for your sample Spreadsheet. Please be careful this. So when you use this script, please use your sample Spreadsheet.**

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `Apologies @Tanaike this script is not what I was looking for exactly. I was wanting a script that checks column P to see if there is a match with E3. And if there is - to paste E3:N7 over it. And if not - to paste E3:N7 at the bottom of the data, in this case Q23:Y27`, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. So I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.